# Как GridLayoutManager рассчитывает высоту строк

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

Хочу разобраться по какому принципу `GridLayoutManager` рассчитывает высоту строк.

В двух строках таблицы есть фотографии разных размеров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так их рассчитывает `GridLayoutManager` на девайсе 480 * 800:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как на примере выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С шириной фотографий все просто - есть сумма 4 фотографий - 600 px, а есть 480px - ширина дисплея. 
600 / 480 = 1,25
Потом для каждой фотографии 150 / 1,25 = 120 вместе с padding выходит то, что нужно.
В `RecyclerView` есть

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

А как понять и разобраться с высотой? Почему первый ряд иименно 174px, а второй 159px?